# Can "Produce a Miracle for the Masses" be used to replace multiple cubes?

Tags: lords-of-waterdeep

The card states:

> Once per round, whenever you take an action that provides any [white],
>   you can also replace [orange], [black], or [purple] with [white].

The white cube is qualified by "**any**", but the text does not indicate "**a** cube" or "**one** cube", though the flavor text may imply only one:

> "Another cleric called to the cause."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only do it once.

When you see a cube on a card, it means *one* cube. This isn't explicitly stated in the rules, but it should be apparent from the way cards always show a number of cubes, and any time there's not a known number of cubes, it's qualified. For example, this very card says "...any {white}..." rather than just "...{white}..." to make it clear that it triggers just once when you receive any number of clerics. If you look through other cards, I think you'll find you've always interpreted a single cube to mean a single adventurer.

So you could more clearly transcribe the card as:

> Once per round, whenever you take an action that provides any clerics, you can also replace *a fighter, a rogue, or a wizard with a cleric*.

And since it says you can only make that replacement once, you can only replace one cube.